# We can't create /var folder

Tags: macos, filesystem

There is `/private/var` folder, but we can't create `/var` folder!
Why?

I'm using OS X El Capitan 10.11.5.

Answer (score 6):

You can't create it because, `/var` is a symlink to `/private/var`.

```
> ls -lha /var
lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 root  wheel    11B Jan 13  2016 /var -> private/var
```